# Page posts scheduled via Graph API do not appear in Meta Business Suite

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I schedule photo posts to be published later on my Facebook page via Graph API. These scheduled posts contain a message, one photo and a comment.

The scheduled posts DO appear in Creator Studio, but do NOT appear in Meta Business Suite. (Once the post is published, instantly appears in Meta Business Suite as well)

I have been fine with it, but Facebook plans to shut down Creator Studio, thus I will need to have these posts in Meta Business Suite.

How could I solve this problem and make scheduled posts appear in Meta Business Suite?

I tried simpler posts (e.g. only photo, without message and comment) to no avail.

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Did you figure it out @viktor-szuper?

Comment: @AnmolDeep Unfortunately, I could not figure it out, so I created a simple Creator Studio-like application to manage (modify, delete) my scheduled posts

Comment: Is it proprietary, or have you made it open source? Would love to go through that code. I am new to Graph API. Is there a video playlist on Youtube or some other resource you would like to recommend?